# how does gcc compiler produces machine/processor independent binary?

Tags: gcc, binaryfiles

my question could be bit dummy, but i always had this question in my mind.

**How does the gcc at compile time determines for which target machine/processor is it getting build-ed for ?**

**Are the instructions generated by gcc/g++ are target system independent ?**

For example i have a x86_64 machine with intel based , AMD based , Motorola based system etc...

**Do all the processors have the same instruction set and opcode associated with it ?**

**if not the machine-code/binary generated by gcc have some kind of a runtime check ?**

Thanks in advance for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit complicated. It depends on how **GCC** was configured and compiled during installation. On my Ubuntu 16.04 x64 system there is a **GCC** installation.

If in terminal I type `gcc -v`, I'll get `--target=x86_64-linux-gnu`, which means **GCC** will produce code for x64 Linux. `--host=x86_64-linux-gnu` means **GCC** itself is x64 linux application. More of this at the [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Configure-Terms.html).

Another useful output to look at is `--with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32` - it means I could compile for default 64bit application together with two types of 32bit applications (-m32 and -mx32).

Last but not least is `--with-tune=generic`, which means apps will be compiled for some *generic* x64 platform and user should be able to run them anywhere on x64 Linux box.

THere are two options to override - `-march` and `-mtune`. Arch option will tell compiler to use intruction specific for a given CPU. Tune will tune the code generation to fit best given CPU. CPU is either specific platform (like, say, sandybridge), generic platform (usually a default) or `native`, where **GCC** during compilation will check the host CPU and perform code generation/tuning for it.

Last set of option covers the setting for FPU - you could select which unit to use (x87 or SSE2+), instruction set (SSE2, 3, 4, AVX) etc. MOre into the this [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/gcc/x86-Options.html#x86-Options).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when u specify --target=x86_64-linux-gnu as a gcc option its a generic x86_64 arch system right ? So does that mean all processors follow the same instruction set ?

Comment: @Ranjith Yes, with generic arch it would be generic x86_64 as defined by AMD more than 10 years ago - 16 integer registers, 16 SSE2, 64bit ISA, flat address space. `So does that mean all processors follow the same instruction set ?` Well, it is minimal subset which is shared by all compatible x64 CPU (from AMD, Intel, VIA), so programs targeting generic x86_64 shall work on any of those CPUs.